# Read .coverage file outside VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing, code-coverage

I generated .coverage file using the Performance Tools in VS2010. I can follow all steps to get the .coverage file in command line.

but i have VS2010 Professional version, so that i cannot open the .coverage file and see the coverage inside VS2010 (or can I do so?). Is there a way to see the results another way, using freeware etc... ?

For instance is there a way to get the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll` and have it working fully in VS2010 PRO ?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't taking out the mentioned DLL out of the Premium or Ultimate editions a violation of the legal terms and conditions of these tools?